# Redirecting stdout to pipe in C

Tags: c, redirect, fork, pipe, stdout

Here's a program I'm trying to make:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* arguments[] = {"superabundantes.py", NULL};

    int my_pipe[2];
    if(pipe(my_pipe) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
    }

    pid_t child_id;
    child_id = fork();
    if(child_id == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
    }
    if(child_id == 0) // child process
    {
        close(my_pipe[0]); // child doesn't read
        dup2(my_pipe[1], 1); // redirect stdout

        execvp("cat", arguments);

        fprintf(stderr, "Exec failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        close(my_pipe[1]); // parent doesn't write

        char reading_buf[1];
        while(read(my_pipe[0], reading_buf, 1) > 0)
        {
            write(1, reading_buf, 1); // 1 -> stdout
        }
        close(my_pipe[0]);
        wait();
    }
}
```

I want to execute the exec in the child redirecting the stdout of the child to the parent (through the pipe). I think the problem might be related to dup2, but I haven't used it before.

Comment: Please specify what "the problem" is instead of just dumping your code to let us find out. If you don't know what the problem is, then add error reporting to your program.

Comment: Don't resolve your problem, but you must specify a int *sts for wait() function (can be NULL).

Comment: thanks for this! works perfect after change  
char* arguments[] = {"cat', "superabundantes.py", NULL};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *also* provide `argv[0]` when you call exec. So your arguments should read:

```
char* arguments[] = {"cat", "superabundantes.py", NULL};
```

Comment: Yes! You're right. char* arguments[] = {"cat", "superabundantes.py", NULL}; execvp(argv[0], arguments); It works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //char* arguments[] = {"cat","tricky.txt", NULL};
    char* arguments[] = {"./son1", NULL};
    int my_pipe[2];
    if(pipe(my_pipe) == -1)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
    }

    pid_t child_id;
    child_id = fork();
    if(child_id == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
    }
    if(child_id == 0) // child process
    {
        close(my_pipe[0]); // child doesn't read
        dup2(my_pipe[1], 1); // redirect stdout

        execvp(arguments[0], arguments);

        fprintf(stderr, "Exec failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        close(my_pipe[1]); // parent doesn't write

        char reading_buf[1];

        while(read(my_pipe[0], reading_buf, 1) > 0)
        {
           write(1, reading_buf, 1); // 1 -> stdout
        }

        close(my_pipe[0]);
        wait();
   }
```

}

/*
  if ./son1 returns
  printf() in son1 will be output by write(1 ..) in parent
  if son1 is in dead loop then
  printf() in son1 will NOT be output by write(1 ..) in parent

```
void main()
{
    printf( "***** son run *****\n\r" );
    return;
    while(1);
}
```

any idea?
*/